# Accessing element of an array with iterator instead of position in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, iterator, iteration

I would like to know if there are iterators for array in Swift, like in CPP, which permits to avoid the using of *position* to access to the next element of an array.

Actually, I use *position + 1* in my array to access its next element:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

func arrayToString(success : String -> Void)
{
    var str = String()

    var myFunc : (Int -> Void)!

    myFunc = {

        if $0 < array.count
        {
            str += array[$0]

            myFunc($0 + 1)
        }
        else
        {
            success(str)
        }
    }

    myFunc(0)
}

arrayToString({

    println($0)

})
```

I'm looking for a solution usable like this:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

func arrayToString(success : String -> Void)
{
    var str = String()

    var myFunc : (Iterator -> Void)!

    myFunc = {

        if $0 != nil
        {
            str += array[$0]

            myFunc($0.next)
        }
        else
        {
            success(str)
        }
    }

    myFunc(array.first)
}

arrayToString({

    println($0)

})
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is to use a generator:

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var g = array.generate()
var str = String()
for (var i = g.next(); i != nil; i = g.next()) {
  str += i!
}
```

This is very handy when you want to parse command line arguments:

```
var args = Process.arguments.generate()
while let arg = args.next() {
  if (arg == "--output") {
    let output = args.next()!
    ...
  }
}
```

In Swift 3, this now becomes:

```
var args = Process.arguments.makeIterator()
while let arg = args.next() {
  if (arg == "--output") {
    let output = args.next()!
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was really looking something like this!

Answer (score 2):

**-** I can think of a work around which can be implemented here, and its the use of `map` **function** of `Array`.

**Iteration over each Elements:**

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr.map { a in print("\(a + 1) ") }
```

**Output:**

> 2 3 4 5 6

**-** So in this way you can achieve the **iteration** over each element of the `Array` in `Swift`.

Comment: The _idiomatic_ way to write this is `arr.forEach { print($0) }`, because it doesn't construct another array, the way `map()` does.